# Test fails when it mimics proven documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

In my own react app using typescript, I am trying to mimic [this](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/) documentation for react-testing-library where it tests react router routes and links. In that documentation, the demo is not using typescript, but far as I know that should not matter. In my app below, I have a similar setup, but my test is failing.

I cannot see a difference among the App and App.test files between my app and the docs. I did note that there is a difference between the package.json files, but I'm no expert in that realm.

When they seem the same to me, why do my tests fail, but the tests in the docs pass?

UPDATED: Error
[image]

App.tsx

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const Home = () => <div>here is home</div>
  const Images = () => <div>here is Images</div>

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Link to="/" >home</Link>&nbsp;
      <Link to="/images" >images</Link>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
        <Route path="images" element={ <Images /> } />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.test.tsx

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import { BrowserRouter, MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event"
import App from "./App"

describe('Render text', () => {

  it.only('images route test', async () => {
    render(<App />, {wrapper: BrowserRouter})
    expect(screen.getByText(/here is home/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
    const user = userEvent.setup()
    user.click(screen.getByText(/images/i))
    screen.debug()    // <-- shows home page
    expect(screen.getByText(/here is images/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

package.json, react-testing-library documentation

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json, my app

```
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.36",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Screenshots of error messages are not acceptable here. **Edit** the **message text** into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only noticeable difference I see between the RTL docs and your code is that their code waits for the UI change to occur from the clicking of the link.

> ```
> test('full app rendering/navigating', async () => {
>   render(<App />, {wrapper: BrowserRouter})
>   const user = userEvent.setup()
>
>   // verify page content for default route
>   expect(screen.getByText(/you are home/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
>
>   // verify page content for expected route after navigating
>   await user.click(screen.getByText(/about/i)) // <-- awaited
>   expect(screen.getByText(/you are on the about page/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
> })
> ```

Try also `await`-ing in your test code.

```
it.only('images route test', async () => {
  render(<App />, { wrapper: BrowserRouter });

  expect(screen.getByText(/here is home/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

  screen.debug()    // <-- shows home page

  const user = userEvent.setup();
  await user.click(screen.getByText(/images/i)); // <-- await component rerender

  screen.debug()    // <-- should show images page now

  expect(screen.getByText(/here is images/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```